# Getting Null Pointer Exception error

Tags: android

I'm getting data form the XML file like this:-

```
   <posts>
          <page id="1">
                      <title>
                            <![CDATA[ Tile no. 1 ]]>
                      </title>

                      <smallimage>
                                 http://www.xyz.com/right.jpg
                      </smallimage>
          </page>

          <page id="2">
                      <title>
                            <![CDATA[ Tile no. 2 ]]>
                      </title>
          </page>

          <page id="3">
                      <title>
                            <![CDATA[ Tile no. 3 ]]>
                      </title>

                      <smallimage>
                                 http://www.xyz.com/left.jpg
                      </smallimage>
          </page>
  </posts>
```

this is example of my XML in which i'm getting element  and , i'm getting 10 page in single url in which 10 are present but not 10  are preset. It may be 3 or 6 or 1.

In my code i'm using SAX parser to parse this XML file i'm getting my data and able to display on the list View but i'm able to display images with them.

For displaying images i'm using LazlyList Example (ImageLoader Class).

Here is my code below:-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static final String URL = "http://www.xyz.com/api.php?page_id=1";

    ItemList itemList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String XML = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

        System.out.println("This XML is ========>"+XML);

       try
       {
           SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
           XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

           /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
           MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
           xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

           ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes());
           xr.parse(new InputSource(is));
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }

      itemList = MyXMLHandler.itemList;

      ArrayList<String> listItem= itemList.getTitle();
      ArrayList<String> listManu = itemList.getSmallimages();


      System.out.println("(ListItem)=======>"+listItem);
      System.out.println("(ListManu)=======>"+listManu);

    //  String ar[];
      Object obj[]=listManu.toArray();
      String[] stringArray=Arrays.asList(obj).toArray(new String[obj.length]);
      System.out.println("Array to String"+Arrays.toString(stringArray));
     // ar=(String[]) listManu.toArray();


     ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
     myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, listItem, stringArray);
     lview.setAdapter(adapter);        

}
```

myAdapter.java

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    ArrayList<String> listTitle;
    String [] data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;


    Activity activity;

    public myAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listTitle, String[] d) {
        super();
        this.listTitle = listTitle;
        this.data = d;


        this.activity = activity;
        this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        ImageView image;


    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder title;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(view==null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lview_row, null);
            title = new ViewHolder();

            title.txtViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            title.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            view.setTag(title);
        }
        else
        {
            title = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        title.txtViewTitle.setText(listTitle.get(position));


        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], title.image);

        return view;
    }
}
```

\

when i'm using return data.length then i'm getting images and tile only no. of images are present  because String [] is storing images only not the spaces...

```
public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
```

but when i changed data.length to listTitle.size()

```
public int getCount() {
            return listTitle.size();
```

getting the Null Pointer Exception i'm using listTilte.size() because it give the full list...

Any one plz suggest me how can i able to solve this issue and getting images and full title data in the list view and where images is present where only i will getting image with title otherwise only title is display on the list view...

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: "Getting Null Pointer Exception error" Where?

Comment: hi zapl... i update my question plz have a look thanks...

Comment: 2 Coments. First, never use httpconnection without a Thread and worst on the OnCreate Method <---- very very very bad. Second, use Log.d("TAG",text) instead of system println

Comment: Well, why never? Perhaps it is planned to be moved in a separate thread later. And why it is so bad using println. Anyway these comments do not help

Comment: Never because if you target your app to Android api 14 this code not compile. Log because is the standar in android (ofc you can use that you want!)

Answer (score 0):

if you get nullpointerexception when using `listTitle.size();` then listTitle is not ininitialized.

your codesample does not contain code for listTitle except in the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to help you without seeing the source code for your your MyXMLHandler. Working with parsing XML is a real pain, the data you are fetching, do you also control the server generating the data? If so I would strongly suggest you instead send it by JSON...

JSON are a way of writing objects in a javascript-like syntax that is easily machine parsable, your list could look something like this:

```
{"posts:":
  [ 
    {"pageId": 1, "title":"sometitle", "smallImage":"someimage.png"},
    {"pageId": 2, "title":"sometitle", "smallImage":"someimage.png"},
    {..... etc }
  ]
}
```

To create this in PHP all you have to do is:

```
class PostsList {
  var $posts = array();
}

class Post {
 var $pageId;
 var $title;
 var $smallImage;
 function Post($pageId, $title, $smallImage) {
  $this->pageId = $pageId; $this->title = $title; $this->smallImage = $smallImage;
 }
}
$posts = new PostsList();
$posts->posts[] = new Post(1, "some title", "image.png");
$posts->posts[] = new Post(2, "some other title", "image2.png");

echo json_encode($posts);
```

Now in java you make the same objects: ie

```
class PostsList { 
  public ArrayList<Post> posts; 
}
class Post { 
  public int pageId; 
  public String title; 
  public String smallImage;
}
```

Then you get GSON (which works in android), you then do:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String jsonData = getDataFromServer();
PostsList gotFromServer = gson.fromJson(jsonData, PostsList.class);
```

Voila! You have all the posts allready parsed into java objects, you can even make the PostsList object into an adaptor for use with list...

After I became more familiar with JSON I have stopped using XML for RPC, JSON data is just soooooo much easier to work with, also it is very easy to later add or remove fields...